# What is the Supertest equivalent of a cURL command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, jestjs, supertest

As of now, I am testing a set of code with Jest and Supertest. I have a few curl commands that I'd like to replace with Supertest functions if possible. I am able to check if the service is online, however, I'm not able to test true GET and POST commands. I know it is possible, but I'm not sure how to translate. So far, I have the following cURL command:

```
curl -X POST \
'example.com/v5/data?auth=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&to=foobar@foo.com' \
  -F 'images=@/Users/me/Desktop/test.png' \
  -F 'details={
          "details": [
            {
                 "summary":"some cool project",
                 "href": "example.com/a/b/c",
            }
        ]
}'
```

The above does exactly as I'd like, however, the following supertest functions do not, and fail with timeouts.

```
let path = 'example.com/v5/data?auth=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&to=foobar@foo.com'
let image = '@/Users/me/Desktop/test.png'
let details = {'details': ['summary':'some cool project', 'href':'example.com/a/b/c']}

// :::::::::: PASSED
it('server online', function(done){
    request(app).get("/")
    .expect(200)
    .expect('<html></html>')
})

// :::::::::: FAILED
it('post test.img', function(done){
    request(app).post(path,object)
    .expect(200)
    .expect('???')
})

// :::::::::: FAILED
it('get test.img', function(done){
    request(app).get(path)
    .expect(200)
    .expect('???')
})
```

I'm sure that I have just put everything in the wrong location, so I was hoping that someone could potentially correct me here.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to [ping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping) the server on the testing script. 
They have many readable response and easy to understand.